# For each value in col A finding number of values in column B that are greater than it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

Let's say I have a table with 2 columns - A & B.

Using plain SQL (No scripts/cursors etc.), how do I (window function?) calculate for EACH value in column A the number of values in column B that are bigger/smaller than it?

Thanks you.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

You would use conditional aggregation:

```
select a,
       sum(case when b < a then 1 else 0 end)
from t
group by a;
```

Window functions don't seem appropriate to this question.